# C++ How to add libraries to minGW

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw

I am really confused at why my programs aren't working with my opengl library. In my minGW folder, my libopengl32.a file is in the lib folder, and my .h files are in the include folder. Everything seems to work out except for the fact that my compiler can't find the library.
In the command prompt I type in:

```
g++ main.cpp -libopengl32
```

This doesn't work, the compiler says it cannot find -libopengl32. I thought it would work because I put the libraries in the lib folder and the .h files in the include folder. Why isn't it working? How come it can't find the file?
Thanks.
P.S. I have a windows OS

Answer (score 1):

change to `g++ main.cpp -lopengl32`

Comment: the library name is libopengl32. So it would be -llibopengl32 without spaces between -l libopengl32? Or do you take out the lib and change to -lopengl32?

Comment: take out the lib part. usual pattern is lib<SomeName>.a should be linked with -lSomeName

Comment: did it work? would appreciate an "accept" on the answer in that case. :)

Comment: Well, I it worked I think, but there were still so many errors and I just gave up on c++. Anyway, I don't have enough reputation to vote up your question. :(